# Newbie GIT Help - Making a second Repository

Tags: gitlab

I currently work on solutions / projects within a single GIT repository, in Visual Studio. The commits I make are to a local folder on the Visual Studio server, and then I use the command 'git push origin master' (after having changed directory to my local folder / repository) to push commits to a Gitlab in my company's corporate space. The purpose of this is less about using branches and software development (as I am the only person who does any work on this), and more about having a way to rollback changes and keep a master copy off the server.

I now want a fresh copy of this GIT repository, so I can use that as a new baseline for an application migration. I will still continue to work on the existing repository too.

What is the best way to make a copy of the existing repository, that I can treat as a totally separate thing, without accidently messing up my existing config on the server? Should I do the clone from the Gitlab? Or clone locally and then push that up to the new space in my Gitlab? Honestly, I'm a bit confused at this point about the proper model for this stuff.

....................

Comment: This is what branches are for.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'd like to fork the project: keep the existing repo and start a new, separate repo based on the old one.

1. Browse to your project in Gitlab
2. On the main repo screen, click "fork" in the top right
3. Select a new/ the same organisation as you'd like
4. The project is now forked!
   From here, you can clone the fork to your local machine in a new folder. These are now separate projects, and code updates can be added, committed and pushed to the separate repos.

Comment: This was just the answer I was looking for. Thanks very much Iain!

Comment: No problem! Hope the new project goes well.